# Casting all elements of a list of lists to float in python

Tags: casting, python-3.5

I'm trying to cast all elements on a list of lists to float but when I do it like on the first loop below and then print their type, their types keep being the original ones.

```
for x in f:
    for a in x:
        a = float(a) 

for x in f:
    for a in x:
        print(type(a),a)
```

Out of the print I get

```
<class 'numpy.str_'> 0.0
<class 'float'> 0.0
<class 'float'> 1.0
<class 'float'> nan
<class 'numpy.float64'> 0.3
```

Shouldn't the first loop change the elements' types?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
for x in f:
    for a in x:
        a = float(a)
```

This does not update the element in the list like you'd expect.  You're just assigning `a` to a new variable.

There are many ways of doing this but one way would be to recreate your list.  Here's a simple example

```
a = [ "1", "2", "3" ]
a = [ float(x) for x in a ]
print(a)  # Yield [1.0, 2.0, 3.0]
```

Another way is directly update the item in the list

```
for index, a in enumerate(x):
    x[index] = float(a)
```

Comment: Just one thing, in your second solution I think index should be first on the loop

Comment: Opps, my bad.  Updating